# jQuery selector difference

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this element in the DOM: `<div id="main" class="main"></div>`.  Is there any difference between selecting the element by $('#main') vs $('.main:first')?

EDIT:
Forgot to mention that this is assuming that this element is the only element with classname "main".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> EDIT: Forgot to mention that this is assuming that this element is the only element with classname "main".

There is NO difference since there is only one `.main` and so selecting by `$('#main')` or `$('.main')` would return you the same result.

In performance aspect there is but you can ignore it, unless you use high-fi animations or huge DOM manipulation.

`$('#main')` - Faster, neater and efficient

`$('.main:first')` - class selector is slower compared to ID selector and `:first` filter is slow.

-> You don't need `:first`, just `$('.main')` will return you the desired result.

**Other options** -

`$('.main')` - Slower than ID selector

`$('div.main')` - Slower than ID Selector still better than just $('.main')

**Proof** - http://jsperf.com/jquery-class-vs-id-v2

Comment: Class selectors are pretty damn fast.

Comment: @BoltClock Yes it is, but not as fast as ID selector http://jsperf.com/jquery-class-vs-id-v2

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If that element is not the first element with the class `main` then it will not be selected.

Answer (score 1):

$("#main") will probably be a bit faster since it uses the ID.

Also, if you add another element with the .main class before the original one, then it would fail.

Answer (score 0):

The ID Selector is stronger as jQuery traverses the DOM ID's should be unique (meaning only 1 per view) whereas you can have multiple main classes.